# How to install "util" on anaconda spyder 5

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I'm trying to execute this code below:

```
from util import  testDlibFaceDetector, saveFaces_hogFaceDetector

# choose method to detect faces: HAAR Cascade or HOG algorithm
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # testFaceRecognitionAlgorithm() #HAAR Cascade
    # testDlibFaceDetector() # HOG
    # saveFaces()
    saveFaces_hogFaceDetector()
```

but in everytime I get the same result which is :

```
runfile('E:/code pfe/liveness-master/4_liveness net/untitled0.py', wdir='E:/code pfe/liveness-master/4_liveness net')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "E:\code pfe\liveness-master\4_liveness net\untitled0.py", line 8, in <module>
    import util

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util'
```

sp please can you show me how to install it correctly , I found the git clone method but I didn't find it useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid installing `util`, you need to place the file that imports it in the same directory where `util` is.

Comment: could you tell me how to do so because I didn't get it really well please

Comment: You're using an untitled file in Spyder now, which won't work. So please save that file and using the Windows file explorer, move it to the same directory where you have `util.py`.